# System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, system.diagnostics

I'm encountering a problem, but with a more recent version. I receive an error stating "System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=6.0.0.0," although Azure.Core utilizes version 6.0.0.1.

When I downgrade my NuGet package from 6.0.0.1 to 6.0.0.0, I encounter a different error: "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'."

Attempting to switch from version 6.0.0.0 to 4.0.4.0 results in a compatibility issue with "Azure.Core" and "Azure.Storage.Blobs," which do not support System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.4.0. Despite having consistent references to version 6.0.0.1 in both my web.config and the app.config of my new DLL, the error persists.

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.1" newVersion="6.0.0.1" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

LOGS:

```
=== Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51 (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/System/testsystem/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\System\testsystem\bin Calling assembly : Azure.Storage.Blobs, Version=12.19.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8.
LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\System\testsystem\web.config LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config. LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51 LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/4a4892e4/1a9eb44/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.DLL. WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision Number ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated. DATE/TIME: 11/21/2023 10:53:57 PM
```

I have upgrade and downgrade packages.

Comment: Do you have both an explicit package reference, as well as a transitive dependency?  Do you have more than one transitive dependency? What version is actually copied to your output folder? Do you use a legacy project or SDK-style project? If you have a legacy project it is possible for the references in the project file to be different from the packages-file, and this can cause all kinds of issues. [Reinstalling the package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages) may solve some of the issues.

Comment: @NelsonRolandoRodriguezHerna, do you have the package `System.Net.Http` installed in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the solution: The issue was that the `<dependentAssembly>` tags in the `web.config` were not being recognized, preventing the new dll from functioning correctly. This was due to the `<configuration>` tag containing namespace attributes, which resulted in the `<assemblyBinding>` tag being overlooked.

Incorrect configuration: `<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">`

Correct configuration: `<configuration>`

After correcting this, the assembly classes were read properly, allowing me to direct the system to the correct dlls.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to multiple reasons:

Follow the below steps to resolve the issue:

1. Install **`System.Net.Http`** package with version **4.3.***.

[image]

3. Upgrade the package **`System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource`** to the ***latest version*** as mentioned in the [MSQ&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1302703/im-having-difficulty-connecting-to-my-azure-file-s).

```cs
   <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

4. The error you are getting could be because of ***cleaning the dependencies*** which are already available with different versions.

**Add below configuration in .csproj:**

```cs
<ItemGroup>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
</ItemGroup>

//To preserve selected dependencies only.
<ItemGroup>
    <FunctionsPreservedDependencies Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" />
</ItemGroup>
```

5. ***Clean and rebuild the solution*** in Visual Studio.

**References:**

1. [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2349)

Comment: Thanks for this, the current version that I have in my azure dll its System.Net.Http 4.3.4. Also I have updated my "System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" to the latest version 8.0.0.0. Where or in what file should I add this configurations tags <ItemGroup> ?

Comment: Did you try running your code and check if you're still getting the error.

Comment: Stills same issue. Now Im getting to update to version 4.0.4.0

Comment: === Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/System/testsystem/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\System\testsystem\bin
Calling assembly : Azure.Storage.Blobs, Version=12.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8.

Comment: ===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\System\testsystem\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51

Comment: LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/4a4892e4/1a9eb44/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/4a4892e4/1a9eb44/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.DLL.

Comment: LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/System/testsystem/bin/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

Comment: Sorry I had to chunk the log @Pravallika KV

Comment: Can you try with version 7.0.0 of `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource`

Comment: Stills same error:
MESSAGE: Error in GetBytes: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: I discovered the solution: The issue was that the `<dependentAssembly>` tags in the `web.config` were not being recognized, preventing the new dll from functioning correctly. This was due to the `<configuration>` tag containing namespace attributes, which resulted in the `<assemblyBinding>` tag being overlooked. 

Incorrect configuration: `<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">`

Correct configuration: `<configuration>`

After correcting this, the assembly classes were read properly, allowing me to direct the system to the correct dlls.